# Trying to isolate a rectangle in a list of rectangles C#

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, mouse

I have made a grid of rectangles using a list. So far, if the user clicks any one of the those rectangles, all of them will become red. However, that is not what I'm aiming for, however, my goal of making the one rectangle in which the user clicked is proving hard for me.

My code so far is this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Quoridor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        private Pen pen = Pens.Black;        

        List<Rectangle> recList = new List<Rectangle>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++)
                {
                    recList.Add(new Rectangle(x * 50, y * 50, 100, 100));
                }

                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            foreach (Rectangle rec in recList)
            {                             
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rec);
            }

        }


        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point cursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

            foreach (Rectangle rec in recList)
            {
                if (rec.Contains(cursor))
                {
                    pen = Pens.Red;
                }
            }

            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my second month since I started coding, please go easy on me :D

Comment: My questions never get answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your form has only one pen. This piece of code here:

```
        foreach (Rectangle rec in recList)
        {
            if (rec.Contains(cursor))
            {
                pen = Pens.Red;
            }
        }
```

is effectively saying "If the cursor is in any one of my rectangles, turn the pen red, and then draw everything again with the red pen".

You want each rectangle to have its own pen.

Here's an approach. This is just rough code which I haven't tested. If it doesn't compile then you have to work out why yourself. But this approach should help you:

```
namespace Quoridor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        class RectangleAndPen
        {
             public Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }
             public Pen Pen { get; set; }
        }

        List<RectangleAndPen> recList = new List<RectangleAndPen>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++)
                {
                    recList.Add(new RectangleAndPen 
                               { 
                                   Rectangle = new Rectangle(x * 50, y * 50, 100, 100),
                                   Pen = Pens.Black
                               }
                }

                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            foreach (RectangleAndPen r in recList)
            {                             
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(r.Pen, r.Rectangle);
            }

        }


        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point cursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

            foreach (RectangleAndPen r in recList)
            {
                if (r.Rectangle.Contains(cursor))
                {
                    r.Pen = Pens.Red;
                }
            }

            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3662652 - You're welcome. If this solves your problem, please press the "tick" button next to this answer.